# VerifyListener not allowing CTRL + X action in SWT Text

Tags: java, validation, swt, listener

When I add a `VerifyListener` to allow typing numbers only to a `Text`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> function is not working. The content of the text box is not cleared. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> works fine.

What might be the reason for this?

```
@Override
public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
    char inputChar = e.character;
    int keyCode = e.keyCode;
    e.doit = Character.isDigit(inputChar) || keyCode == SWT.BS || keyCode == SWT.DEL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your verify listener.

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get a chance to try the code as I found a way to handle it already. I posted it below. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
 public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
      char inputChar = e.character;
      int keyCode = e.keyCode;
      String inputString = e.text;
      e.doit = Character.isDigit(inputChar) || keyCode == SWT.BS || keyCode==SWT.DEL||inputString=="";
}
```

I add a check on the text obtained from the Text widget if it is "", and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You specifically need to allow the `Text` to be empty, i.e. in your `Listener` for `SWT.Verify`, check if it's empty and *then* check if it's a number. This will do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    text.addListener(SWT.Verify, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            Text source = (Text) event.widget;
            String oldString = source.getText();

            String newString =  oldString.substring(0, event.start) + event.text + oldString.substring(event.end);

            if(newString.length() == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Double.parseDouble(newString); // Or Integer.parseInt(newString);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    event.doit = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```